# Logs Parse Errors In PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, custom-error-handling

I am working on logging errors in php. I create user define error handler and log the error and save it into DB. There are few type of errors which i am not able to log.

**My Error Handler Code...**

```
<?php


/**
  * Parameters:
  *  $errno:   Error level
  *  $errstr:  Error message
  *  $errfile: File in which the error was raised
  *  $errline: Line at which the error occurred
  */

function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{  
  switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
      // Send an e-mail to the administrator
     // error_log("Error: $errstr \n Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile \n", DEST_EMAIL, ADMIN_EMAIL);
 echo "Error: $errstr \n  on line $errline in file $errfile";

 //stack trace
 $host='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=logs';
$user='root';
$password='';
$con=new PDO($host,$user,$password);
$trace=json_encode(debug_backtrace());
$qry=$con->prepare("insert into error_log (error_type,error_message,error_file,error_line,stack_trace) values('".$errno."','".$errstr."','".$errfile."','".$errline."','".$trace."')");
$qry->execute();

      // Write the error to our log file
    //  error_log("Error: $errstr \n Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
echo "<br>";     
     break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
      // Write the error to our log file
      //error_log("Warning: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      echo "$errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n";
       //stack trace
 $host='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=logs';
$user='root';
$password='';
$con=new PDO($host,$user,$password);
$trace=json_encode(debug_backtrace());
$qry=$con->prepare("insert into error_log (error_type,error_message,error_file,error_line,stack_trace) values('".$errno."','".$errstr."','".$errfile."','".$errline."','".$trace."')");
$qry->execute();

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
      // Write the error to our log file
      //error_log("Notice: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);

     echo "$errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n";
      //stack trace
 $host='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=logs';
$user='root';
$password='';
$con=new PDO($host,$user,$password);
$trace=json_encode(debug_backtrace());
$qry=$con->prepare("insert into error_log (error_type,error_message,error_file,error_line,stack_trace) values('".$errno."','".$errstr."','".$errfile."','".$errline."','".$trace."')");
$qry->execute();
     echo "<br>";
      break;

    default:
      // Write the error to our log file
      //error_log("Unknown error [#$errno]: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
  }

  // Don't execute PHP's internal error handler
  return TRUE;
}


// Use set_error_handler() to tell PHP to use our method
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("my_error_handler");

?>
```

**Errors I want Log:**

```
trigger_error("Core Error",E_CORE_ERROR);
trigger_error("Core Warning",E_CORE_WARNING);
trigger_error("Compile Error",E_COMPILE_ERROR);
trigger_error("Compile Warning",E_COMPILE_WARNING);
trigger_error("Strict Error",E_STRICT);
trigger_error("Recoverable Error", E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);
trigger_error("Depreciated Error",E_DEPRECATED);
trigger_error("parse error",E_PARSE);
trigger_error("Error",E_ERROR);
```

I want to log all the above mentioned errors, like when something is missing in code like semicolon etc then we got a syntax error etc... so i want log all that errors.... 
I have searched a lot but could not find a solution which best fits my needs, and on most places it says that these error can not be logged by using custom error handler, but i am sure that these errors can be logged because it is also logged when we check it in ***php_error_log*** file, so i want the WAY to logged it using custom error handler...
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

> Please do not comment or down vote the question because of the code i
>   paste here, this code is just under the development and i did not
>   clean, secure it yet, Only post according / related to the issue.

Comment: `php_error_log` is created by the parser. If your code contains syntax/parse errors (or other type of errors that stops the parser from finish the job correctly), it can't parse the rest of the code and use your custom error handler either. So just because the underlying system can log something doesn't mean that you can. In short: if PHP can't read your code, it can't use your code.

Comment: How do you log errors with problems connecting to the database?

Comment: currently working on only code side, after that i will move to db related issues....